# Get fields set to unique in schema from Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, unique

I have a desire to check which fields in a `schema` are set to `unique`, similar to getting the `indexes` for a `schema` via `MyCollection.collection.getIndexes()`. Can this information be found somewhere on the `schema` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  a: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  b: {
    type: String
  }
});

schema.tree.a.unique; // true
schema.tree.b.unique; // undefined

schema.path('a').options.unique; // true
schema.path('b').options.unique; // undefined
```